# dax parametric query, how to get around the restriction syntax?

Tags: dax

please tell me how to get around the restriction DAX syntax, in all query variable configures @FISKAL_DATE
He announced at the beginning of the query:

```
<Parameters>
<Parameter>
  <Name> FISKAL_DATE </ Name>
  <Value> 2015-09-01 </ Value>
</ Parameter>
</ Parameters>
```

Then a lot of calculations, which is found:

```
CALCULATE (SUM ( 'FACT' [SUM_LINE]), 'DATE' [DATE] = DATEVALUE (@FISKAL_DATE))
```

It's all good, but there are also calculations:

```
CALCULATE (SUM ( 'FACT' [SUM_LINE]), DATESBETWEEN ( 'Calendar' [month year], DATEVALUE ( "2015-07-01"), DATEVALUE ( "2015-07-01"))
```

If the date is replaced by a variable, it would be a mistake because DATEADD (@ FISKAL_DATE, -2, MOTTH) works exclusively with columns rather than variable, as well as many other functions. How to get around this fact?

Answer (score 0):

GOOD

```
<Parameters>
<Parameter>
  <Name>FISKAL_DATE</Name>
  <Value>2015-09-01</Value> 
</Parameter>
</Parameters>

.... DATESINPERIOD('DATE'[DATE], DATEVALUE(@FISKAL_DATE) , -3, Month)
```

last 3 month